# How can I write Type Inference Cases in Scala

Tags: scala

I've following [HipsterTree.scala](https://sujitbaniya.com.np/HipsterTree.scala) file. Using this file how can I define cases for Type Inferences in:

```
val tipe : Expression => Type =
attr {
  case IdnExpr(i) =>
    entity(i) match {
      case e : Applicable => UnknownType()
      case e : TypedEntity => e.tipe
      case _ => UnknownType()
    }
  case _ : IntExpr => IntType()
  case _ : FloatExpr => FloatType()
  case _ : BoolExpr => BoolType()

  // FIXME: Add type inference cases for all other expression
  // node types here.

  case _ => UnknownType()
}

  val expTipe : Expression => Set[Type] =
attr {
  // Expected types of dimension expressions.
  case tree.parent(_ : BoundedDim) => Set(IntType())
  case tree.parent(_ : CyclicDim) => Set(IntType())

  case tree.parent.pair(n, ConstantDecl(t,_,_)) =>
    compatTypes(t)
  case tree.parent.pair(n, VarDecl(t,_,_)) =>
    compatTypes(t)

  // FIXME: Add cases to compute the set of expected types for an
  // expression node by inspecting the type of its parent.
  // with the computed expression type.
  case n => compatTypes(tipe(n))
}
```

I would appreciate anyone who could help me adding the case where `FIXME` is indicated

Comment: Looks like you understand pattern matching on Type.  Can you give a specific example for a type inference case that you are struggling with?

Comment: Its Binary, Unary, Function Call and other that I'm missing with. Actually Type Inferencing is new to me. I've got `HipsterTree.scala` for any help